# How to get 30 min interval in time picker in Android N

Tags: android, intervals, android-timepicker

I want to get `30 min interval` from `time picker dialog` and below code works proper below `Android N` but not working in latest device. Below is my code for `activity`.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvSelectedTime;
    private Button btnOpentimePickerDialog;
    private int intHour, intMinute;
    private String strMin = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getIds();
        setListner();
    }

    private void setListner() {
        try {
            btnOpentimePickerDialog.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                switch (view.getId()){
                    case R.id.btnOpentimePickerDialog:
                        openTimePicker();
                        break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    private void openTimePicker() {
        CustomTimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new CustomTimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        Log.e("Log", "selected time----" + hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                        String strTime = hourOfDay + ":"+ minute + ":00";

                updateTime(hourOfDay, minute);
            }
        }, intHour, intMinute, false);
        timePickerDialog.show();

    }

    private void updateTime(int hours, int mins) {
        String timeSet = "";
        if (hours > 12) {
            hours -= 12;
            timeSet = "PM";
        } else if (hours == 0) {
            hours += 12;
            timeSet = "AM";
        } else if (hours == 12)
            timeSet = "PM";
        else
            timeSet = "AM";
//TODO=================Adding zero in one dightleft  and right======================
        if (mins < 10)
            strMin = "0" + mins;
        else
            strMin = String.valueOf(mins);
        // Append in a StringBuilder
        String aTime = new StringBuilder().append(pad(hours)).append(':')
                .append(pad(Integer.parseInt(strMin))).append(" ").append(timeSet).toString();

        Log.e("aTime checking ==>",""+aTime);

        tvSelectedTime.setText(aTime);
    }


    private void getIds() {
        try {
            btnOpentimePickerDialog = findViewById(R.id.btnOpentimePickerDialog);
            tvSelectedTime = findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedTime);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }

}
```

and below is my custom `time picker dialog code`.

```
    public class CustomTimePickerDialog  extends TimePickerDialog {

    private final static int TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL = 30;
    private TimePicker mTimePicker;
    private final OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener;

    public CustomTimePickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener listener, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView) {
        super(context, TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, null, hourOfDay,
                minute / TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL, is24HourView);
        mTimeSetListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateTime(int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour) {
        mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(hourOfDay);
        mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(minuteOfHour / TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which) {
            case BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                if (mTimeSetListener != null) {
                    mTimeSetListener.onTimeSet(mTimePicker, mTimePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                            mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute() * TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL);
                }
                break;
            case BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                cancel();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        try {
            Class<?> classForid = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R$id");
            Field timePickerField = classForid.getField("timePicker");
            mTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(timePickerField.getInt(null));
            Field field = classForid.getField("minute");

            NumberPicker minuteSpinner = (NumberPicker) mTimePicker
                    .findViewById(field.getInt(null));
            minuteSpinner.setMinValue(0);
            minuteSpinner.setMaxValue((60 / TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL) - 1);
            List<String> displayedValues = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i += TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL) {
                displayedValues.add(String.format("%02d", i));
            }
            minuteSpinner.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues
                    .toArray(new String[displayedValues.size()]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In some device, above code is working fine and here is that `screenshot`.

[image]

and in some device I am not able to get time by `30 min interval` like below.

[image]

Actually I want to implement `time picker` like first screen which support in all device.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have resolved my issue using this [library](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) and here is my complete [code](https://github.com/sakib143/TimePicker30MinInterval) which may help someone in the future.

My complete code is in below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    private TextView timeTextView;
    private TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
    private Button timeButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find our View instances
        timeTextView = findViewById(R.id.time_textview);
        timeButton = findViewById(R.id.time_button);

        // Show a timepicker when the timeButton is clicked
        timeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

                timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                        now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                        false
                );

                timePickerDialog.setThemeDark(false);
                timePickerDialog.setTitle("TimePicker Title");
                timePickerDialog.setTimeInterval(1, 30, 60);                            
                timePickerDialog.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#9C27B0"));

                timePickerDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) 
                        Log.d("TimePicker", "Dialog was cancelled");
                    }
                });
                timePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePickerDialog view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
        updateEndTime(hourOfDay,minute);
    }

    private void updateEndTime(int hours, int mins) {
        String timeSet = "";
        if (hours > 12) {
            hours -= 12;
            timeSet = "PM";
        } else if (hours == 0) {
            hours += 12;
            timeSet = "AM";
        } else if (hours == 12) {
            timeSet = "PM";
        } else {
            timeSet = "AM";
        }

        // Append in a StringBuilder
        String aTime = new StringBuilder().append(pad(hours)).append(':')
                .append(pad(mins)).append(" ").append(timeSet).toString();

        timeTextView.setText(aTime);
    }

    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        TimePickerDialog tpd = (TimePickerDialog) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Timepickerdialog");
        if (tpd != null) tpd.setOnTimeSetListener(this);
    }
}
```

My desire output is like this:

[image]

Comment: giving me error for getFragmentManager() for API 28 @sakib