# Android - How to limit date time picker to only every X minutes?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am storing date and time but I need to have it limited **to only be allowed to pick intervals of 30 minutes when the time picker is displayed** so I can't be able for example to pick time *06:11* .

Here is my code that I have.

```
private void showDateTimeDialog(final EditText date_time_in) {

    final Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);

            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hourOfDay);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
                    //format of the calender
                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH:mm");
                    //add the booking in Firebase
                    date_time_in.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
                    Bookings booking = new Bookings(year,month+1,dayOfMonth,hourOfDay,minute);
                    rootDatabaseRef.push().setValue(booking);
                    Toast.makeText(BookingActivity.this, "Appointment successful ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    date_time_in.setText(getString(R.string.select_a_date_and_timeText));
                }
            };

            new TimePickerDialog(BookingActivity.this,timeSetListener,calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),false).show();

        }

    };

    new DatePickerDialog(BookingActivity.this,dateSetListener,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

}
```

What changes do I need to make to limit to 30 minute intervals ?

Comment: There isn't anything to do that.  Your options are either to listen to time changes and round them to the nearest 30 minutes, or to write your own dialog.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555842/how-to-get-30-min-interval-in-time-picker-in-android-n